# CSS - Where are these extra 10 pixels coming from?

Tags: css, space, pixel

[designated_net_testpage002](http://www.designated.net.au/testbed/testpage002/)

You can see on the page, there are thirty white pixels in the middle, I want twenty.  You can also see the borders don't join. 
 Any idea why those extra 10 pixels are there?

Comment: spotlight-feature has no height setting.  The 10px in the middle is part of it though, there is no other info in there.  I don't want to give it a height setting because I want to be able to add content to it in the middle with a white space of 10px at the top and bottom.

Comment: Or do you mean the height is 90px because of the border?  It shouldn't be because the border is using box-sizing.

Comment: @dais see my answer and let me know if i am lagging anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

add

```
spotlight-feature-top {
  -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;    //edited 
    border-color: #333333;
    border-image: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px 0 0;
    float: left;                  //edited 
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;


}

#spotlight-feature-bottom {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;     //edited 
    border-color: #333333;
    border-image: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 0 10px;
    float: left;                      //edited 
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}


#spotlight-feature-bottom-title {
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;            //edited 
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

same result can be achieve by the

```
#spotlight-feature-bottom-right {right: -50px;}


#spotlight-feature-bottom-left {left: -50px;}

#spotlight-feature-bottom-title {margin: 0 auto;}
```

**reason** is that

```
 #spotlight-feature-bottom-title {      margin: 10px auto 0;
                                               ^^^^^
                                              this is the extra 10 px you getting
```

result

[image]

Comment: Oh it's because of the margin in #spotlight-feature-bottom-title.

Comment: The bottom is screwy without the floats too.  Do you know why?

Comment: @dais ya please wait for a second

Comment: @dais now check my answer with the reason and without float

Comment: This is part of a page of stuff and I found the whole lot was broken once I added those float:lefts, unless I added float:left to every main div.

Comment: ya this happen ...in float we have to make float left to all

Comment: i have some image regarding this issue it you want to see them than i can upload them there might be helpfull